# how to change gridview paging when have search result

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have gridview and some textbox that user can search . 
when user search I updated gridview but when changed pageing I bind gridview again and I lost search result . 
how can I change gridview paging without call DataBind Again?

I used this for Paging:

```
   protected void grv_Data_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        grv_Data.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        TicketDataBinding();
    }
```

and my search method is :

```
  protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        using (var ticket = new BLL.Ticket())
        {
            grv_Data.DataSource = tit.SelectList( fromDate, toDate);
            grv_Data.DataBind();
        }}
```

sorry I forgot asp.net webform and I dont know how do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I've included two examples of binding data to a `GridView` where paging still works on filtered data. I hope it helps you.

**1.You can do this completely in .ASPX:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailAddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Search" />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlDS" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailType" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailAddress" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDS" 
        runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conn %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT EmailType, EmailAddress FROM EmailNotifications WHERE EmailAddress LIKE @EmailAddressParam + '%'">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtEmailAddress" DbType="String" Name="EmailAddressParam" DefaultValue="%" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
```

**2.Or in code behind:**

```
public partial class PagingAndSearchingInGridView : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.GetData();
    }

    private void GetData()
    {
        string emailAddress = txtEmailAddress.Text;
        DataTable table = !Page.IsPostBack ? GetEmails() : GetEmails(emailAddress);
        GridView1.DataSource = table;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    private DataTable GetEmails(string emailAddress = "%")
    {
        var table = new DataTable();

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmailType, EmailAddress FROM EmailNotifications WHERE EmailAddress LIKE @EmailAddressParam + '%'", connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddressParam", emailAddress);
                using (var a = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    a.Fill(table);
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        return table;
    }

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        this.GetData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the pageIndex changed event, you can check whether the search button is already clicked or not. When clicking the search button you can set a hiddenfield value to 1 or something like that.

```
     protected void grv_Data_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grv_Data.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
       if(status==1) //Search button is already clicked, means the grid contains searched result
        {
           grv_Data.DataSource = tit.SelectList( fromDate, toDate);
        }
      else
        {
         //Search button is not clicked .. means the grid contains all records.
           TicketDataBinding();
        }
}
```